# In swift 4, uicollectionView can I set minimumLineSpacing for only particular indexPath?

Tags: uicollectionview, swift4

[image: Image Link]

In the picture I have made a **UICollectionView** like the top one.
But I want to make it like the bottom collectionView.
For particular **indexPath** I want more space between cells

I googled but I think there is no way to do that with **minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt**.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method "minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt" is used to give spacing between section not between cells. To achieve the above thing, you can return empty CollectionView cell or you can also return different size for this particular cell.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to achieve this i.e. by using UICollectionViewFlowLayout. You need to subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout, customise it and then assign this to you collection view.